# mongoose query with different input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check in a db if 'test' exists in a document, in a specific field. If exists, I want to increment it by 1, to look like this 'test-1', and then check again in the db, and repeat until it's not found, than save it there.

I don't have a problem with the increment part, just with the mongoose/mongodb part where I need to re-query with the new value. Is there any way that can be done in the same query, multiple times?

Edited: I want to create a new field based on the name, but I want this field to be unique, because I want to use it as an id.

So, for instance, if I have something like `name: 'John Smith'` I want to create a new field in my document like this: `uniqueId: john-smith`, for the same document. The problem is, if another John Smith is inserted in my collection, I want to check if the uniqueId `john-smith` is available, if not I want to append a -1 to it, so it will look like this `john-smith-1`, and so on, until a `john-smith-(number)` is not found, then I will know the id is unique and save it to the document.

One idea would be to use a Model.find() inside of a recursive function with the uniqueId, and repeat until a document is not found. But I was wondering if there might be another way, maybe something less complicated?

mongodb v4.2.3

Comment: So you wanted to update a field in all docs if that field has value `test` to `test-1` ? It's not increment it's appending to string or string concatenation ! Please edit this question with sample docs & required o/p for better understanding..Also include MongoDB version.

Comment: If space is not an issue, you can keep the original name and the duplication count separately, you'll be able to query this easier.